# Firefox addon to organize downloads

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, download-manager

Is there a firefox addon to re-direct downloads to different folders based on conditions?

For example:

```
if file is a video format
   download to "My Videos"
if file is a picture format
   download to "My Pictures"
if file is a music format
   if filename contains "twit" or "sn"
      send to "My Podcasts"
   else
      download to "My Music"
else
   download to "Desktop"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Automatic Save Folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4781).

Answer (score 2):

[Download Sort](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/25) works with the latest version of firefox.

You may wish to browse the [Download Management](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search?q=&cat=1%2C5) plugins list.